# Require an alternative to ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Me again.

I'm trying to render a link in my view, but the parameters are being rendered as query parameters. That is to say, I would like:

```
http://mysite/Discussion/AddMessage?guid=12345&title=MyTitle
```

to be rendered as

```
http://mysite/Discussion/AddMessage/12345/MyTitle
```

How can I achieve this?

Mark

Comment: I think you must use RouteLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes You can using `RouteLink`

You need to add a new `Route` first with a name like below in the RouteConfig after the defeninsion of `DefaultRoute`:-

```
routes.MapRoute(
             name: "NewRoute",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{guid}/{title}",
             defaults: new 
              { controller = "Discussion",
                action = "AddMessage", 
                guid = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                title = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );
```

Then Create a `RouteValueDictionary` to add up your route values and then render it using `RouteLink` extension from `HtmlHelper`..

```
@{
    var dict = new RouteValueDictionary();
    dict.Add("guid", "someguid");
    dict.Add("title", "sometitle");

}

@Html.RouteLink("LinkText", "NewRoute", dict);
```

resulting hyperlink will be generated as

```
<a href="/Discussion/AddMessage/someguid/sometitle">LinkText</a>
```

Comment: That kinda works, only I'm not getting the title. I'm just getting <a href="href="/Discussion/AddMessage/someguid">LinkText</p>. I've tried fiddling with it but to no avail. Help!?

Answer (score 0):

Try RouteLink extension method and send the necessary arguments along.

Checkout [this Haacked post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx)